# Firefox don't show formatting - specific for Code Review community

Tags: bug

I don't see the **bold** or *italics* formatting in the Code Review community in Firefox. In other Stack Exchange communities there is no such problem.

(In Chrome I see those types of formatting also in Code Review pages.)

Is something bad in my configuration of Firefox (version 55.0.3 (32-bit), the newest one this time), or other people experience the same problem?